# Bounding values of a Dirichlet distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, dirichlet-distribution, bounds

Consider $k$ random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k$ such that $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k)$ follow a $\text{Dirichlet}(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ distribution. For a large enough $k$, I am trying to bound/find out (with high probability) what fraction of these $k$ random variables take values between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, for $0 < \alpha < \beta < 1$.